# KQL performance of WHERE condition

Tags: where-clause, azure-data-explorer, kql

Is there any difference in KQL in performance between joining WHERE conditions using ADD statements or adding them separately?

Will smth like

```
Events
| where Source == "myapp"
and Timestamp > ago(7d)
and isnotnull(DeviceId)
and isnotnull(UserId)
```

be faster than

```
Events
| where Source == "myapp"
| where Timestamp > ago(7d)
| where isnotnull(DeviceId)
| where isnotnull(UserId)
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No difference whatsoever. Both queries are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/best-practices), you should use a time filter first because Kusto is highly optimized to use time filters.